# wordnet on different text?

Tags: nltk, wordnet, corpus

I am new to `nltk`, and I find wordnet functionality pretty useful. It gives `synsets`, `hypernyms`, `similarity`, etc. But however it fails to give similarity between locations like 'Delhi'-'Hyderabad' obviously as these words are not in the wordnet corpus.

So, I would like to know, if somehow I can update the wordnet corpus OR create wordnet over a different corpus e.g. Set of pages extracted from wikipedia related to travel? If at all we can create wordnet over different corpus, then what would be the format, steps to do the same, any limitations?

Please can you point me to links that describe the above concerns. I have searched the internet, googled, read portions of nltk book, but I don't have a single hint to above question.

Pardon me, if the question sounds completely ridiculous.

Comment: Check about - DBpedia

Answer (score 2):

For flexibility in measuring the semantic similarity of very specific terms like Dehli or Hyderabad, what you want is not something hand-crafted like WordNet, but an *automatically-learned* similarity measure from a *very large database*. These are [statistical similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_similarity#Statistical_similarity) approaches. Of course, you want to avoid having to train such a model on data yourself...

Thus one thing that may be useful is the Google Distance ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalized_Google_distance), [original paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0412098.pdf)). It seems fairly simple to implement such a measure in a language like R ([code](https://ryouready.wordpress.com/2009/01/12/r-normalized-google-distance-ngd-in-r-part-ii/)), and the original paper reports 87% agreement with WordNet.

Comment: Interesting paper on "Google Distance"!

Answer (score 1):

The similarity measures in Wordnet work as expected because Wordnet measures semantic similarity. In that sense, both are cities, so they are very similar. What you are looking for is probably called `geographic similarity`.

```
delhi = wn.synsets('Delhi', 'n')[0]
print delhi.definition()

# a city in north central India

hyderabad = wn.synsets('Hyderabad', 'n')[0]
print hyderabad.definition()

# a city in southern Pakistan on the Indus River


delhi.wup_similarity(hyderabad)
# 0.9

melon = wn.synsets('melon', 'n')[0]

delhi.wup_similarity(melon)
# 0.3
```

There is a Wordnet extension, called [Geowordnet](https://datahub.io/dataset/geowordnet). I kind of had the same problem as you at one point and tried to unify Wordnet with some of its extensions: [wnext](https://github.com/bogdan-ivanov/wnext). Hope that helps.

Comment: cool. Thanks a lot for your answer. Learnt new thing. But, geographic input was one of the categories i was looking for, there are several others like animals, food items, etc. that I am interested in . Hence I am looking for building wordnet over wikipeida (if it's possible). Any input in this respect?

Comment: What would be the distance measure between food items? Ingredients list?

Comment: I think I have not stated the requirement clearly. Let me try to clarify. Given two word I need to know whether they are similar. e.g. If I give Paris and Donut, then one is food item and other is a location, so I need a process/program to tell that they are dis-similar. For food-items yes I am not clear what would be distance measure, but I am trying to find a way to get a generic output. I thought nltk would help here.

Comment: Indeed, for "Paris" and "Donut", wordnet works as expected. It will give a low similarity score. For "Paris" and "Bangkok", you'll get a high similarity score, since they are both cities. Wordnet measures the semantic distance (the number of edges in the concept graph). From what I understand, you want different distance measures, depending on the concepts. If both arguments are geographic entities then compute the similarity georgraphically, else if ... else compute the semantic similarity